# Iterating over Instagram json

Tags: python, json

I received a JSON object as a response to an Instagram API call.

I want to access the URLs of all pictures in the response, so far I managed to access the first image only:

```
from pprint import pprint
with open('test.json') as data_file:
    mydata = json.load(data_file)
    print mydata["data"][0]["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]
```

I'm struggling how to iterate over mydata correctly.

The json looks roughly like:

```
{
"meta:":{}
"data":[
    {}
    {}
    {}
}
```

I get stuck at this nested loop:

```
for x in mydata["data"]:
   for y in x:
       print y
```

outputs

```
attribution
tags
user
comments
filter
images
link
location
created_time
users_in_photo
caption
type
id
likes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataset = mydata['data']
for data in dataset:
   url = data['images']['standard_resolution']['url']
```

Comment: ah thanks so much! i used a nested loop where none was necessary!

Answer (score 1):

If your first image is accessed as -

```
mydata["data"][0]["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]
```

Then you should iterate over `mydata["data"]` , which is a list, using for loop and get each url from each dictionary in it.

Example -

```
with open('test.json') as data_file:
    mydata = json.load(data_file)
    for img in mydata["data"]:
        print img["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]
```